# Fixed width Dropdown menu with Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, nav

I am having an issue figuring this out.  I'm building this navbar with Flexbox.  I can't seem to figure out how to make all of the submenu items all the same width.  If you run the code below you can see what I mean.  I've tried using the property `{flex: xxx;}` to control the width of the `<li>` elements, but this has not been fruitful.  I've seen other options and theories but nothing works for how  have it.

The dropdown in in the Explore link and is a hoverable option.

Any and all pointers will be much appreciated!

I also have a codepen open on this: [Codepen version](https://codepen.io/Kellum/pen/Gqxmvo)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'helvetica neue', helvetica;
  background: grey;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #000, #fff);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #000, #fff);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #000, #fff);
  background: linear-gradient(left, #000, #fff);
}
nav {
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  /* background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #fff, ##34495e);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #fff, ##34495e);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #fff, ##34495e);
 background: linear-gradient(left, #fff, ##34495e); */
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul a {
  background: #000;
}
nav ul a:hover {
  background: #16a085;
}
nav > ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
nav > ul {
  display: flex;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
nav ul ul li {
  position: relative;
}
nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
.main-nav-links {
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <a href="#0" class="logo">SeeJax</a>

  <ul class="main-nav-links">
    <li><a href="#0">Explore&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <ul class="nav-dropdown">
        <li><a href="#0">Categories</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li><a href="#0">Nightlife</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#0">Parks</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#0">Family Fun</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#0">Food</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#0">Entertainment</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#0">Recreation</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#0">Area</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li><a href="#0">Northside</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#0">Westside</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#0">Southside</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#0">Eastside</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#0">Beaches</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#0">Orange Park</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#0">What is SeeJax?</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#0">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#0">Add Listing</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#0">Log in/Register</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: Make this adjustment: `nav ul a { background: #000; display: block; }`

Comment: @Michael_B,  Oh my god.  Thank you so much.  I have been having a crazy go trying to learn all of this; and with Flexbox thrown into the mix, it's even more confusing trying to use it all in tandem.

Answer (score 0):

make the a tag as a block element, this one thing is enough to achive what you looking for otherwise everything is fine working

```
a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 25px;
  display: block;
}
```